# JPA load objects with Named queries

Tags: jpa, websphere-6.1

I have a JPA object called Customer.java:

```
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name="getAccountWithCheckRangeByService", 
query="SELECT c FROM Customer"})
public Long Id;
public Address address;
//getter and setter
}
```

Now, if I invoke the named query and load the Custoemr object. and then if I do c.getAddress(), will I get the Address loaded? Or do i need to write a separate named query to load the address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean `SELECT c FROM Customer c`.

If you want to ensure that the address is loaded you can use [fetch joins](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.4/apache-openjpa-1.0.4/docs/manual/jpa_overview_query.html#jpa_overview_join_fetch).

`SELECT c FROM Customer c JOIN FETCH c.address`

Answer (score 0):

Try it out - see what happens. If address is a separate entity then yes it will load up all dependent entities - in this case you haven't annotated what the relationship between customer and address is but I'm guessing you've omitted that. You can make it do a lazy load on the relational annotation e.g @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY). If address is simply a column within Customer then yes it will load it up although your JPQL syntax is a bit weird - I would do "SELECT c FROM Customer c". Not sure if your named query will work but it must do if you've tried it out.